# Premiere export video with black frame

Tags: premiere

I'm using Adobe Premiere Pro 6.0 and trying to export video but it always adds a black frame. The output preview shows one picture, the result shows another. It seems like it also crops the video a little. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Here are the settings for exports]

[image]

Comment: Go to the Source window (top left) in Premiere, and see if crop is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I would check

The first thing that comes to mind, the aspect ratio is different from the output to the source. I would check that first (sequence settings)

The seconds thing that comes to mind
Set the crop setting in the export settings to 16:9. That might get rid of the black border for you.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Aspect ratio in sequence sttings is 16:9. Setting the crop to 16:9 in export setting doesn't help.The thing is the exported video should look like output in export window, but it doesn't.